# Remove filter function on every column using tableutils.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/8etdnpdt/3/) , however i wasnt able to use the external js got from raw github. Don't know why. `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kolgepratik/tableutils/master/js/tableutils.js`

The issue here is that the current filtering for table looks like this :
-->sample table :

```
     [column1   table header title] [column2 table header   title]
     [column1 input  for filtering] [column2 input for  filtering] 
     [row 1 table data            ] [row 1 table data            ] 
     [row 2 table data            ] [row 2 table data            ] 
     ... other rows
```

You can see the sample [Search through your table demo](http://kolgepratik.github.io/tableutils/demo.html)
and i dont want the style of having all filter function on every column :

i want to have like this :

```
     [<input>for column1 only for filtering </input>]

     [column1   table header title] [column2 table header   title] 
     [row 1 table data            ] [row 1 table data            ] 
     [row 2 table data            ] [row 2 table data            ]
```

also this is a documentation, and im currently trying to figure it out how to use :

```
/**    * Add Filtering to your table. Here default text filtering on each column is assumed.     */ filter: true,
       /**    * Adding Filtering to your table with more customization.    * The dateFilter will have default functionality of a jQuery UI DatePicker.     */ filter: {    type: [ 'noFilter', 'numeric', 'text', 'dateFilter' ] }
       /**    * Adding Filtering to your table with some more customization.    */ filter: {    type: [
           'noFilter', 
           { 
               /* Add a Drop-down list instead of a Textbox in the column header. */
               type: 'select', 

               /* Options will be generated by the plugin by looking at the values of this column in the table. This will work only with    Client-Side Pagination. */
               generateOptions: true, 

               /* Filter this column numerically. */
               filterType: 'numeric' 
           }, 
           { 
               type: 'select', 
               /* You can provide hard-coded options for the select control. */
               selectOptions: [ { name: 'option1', value: 'value1'}, { name: 'option2', value: 'value2'} ] 

               filterType: 'text'
           },
           { 
               /* Add a DatePicker(jQuery UI DatePicker) instead of a Textbox in the column header. */
               type: 'dateFilter', 

               /* Optional. Specify options as you would specify for a jQuery UI DatePicker. These options will be supplied to the    DatePicker while it is initialized.*/
               options: {}
           }
       ] }
```

Comment: Protip: To access github files without the issues you saw, use the same URL but replace "githubusercontent" or "github" with "githack" and it will work: `https://raw.githack.com/kolgepratik/tableutils/master/js/tableutils.js`. Some very nice chaps made this handy little service that serves up the file with the correct content type and everything.

Comment: thanks, i tried to, but still js is not working http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/8etdnpdt/2/ @GregL

Comment: That's because you define the function `searchRecords()` but never actually _call it_. :-) If you add `searchRecords()` to the end of your JS it does work.

Comment: @GregL,what the.thanks.i thought onload will code it.haha my fault niways.thanks

Comment: seee @GregL http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/8etdnpdt/3/ edited fiddle here